# How to detect if a marker is inside a polygon in google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, coordinates, polygon

I've got loads of coordinates for a polygon in a database. I also have coordinates for an marker in my database.
How do i detect if the marker is inside this polyon.

Note: I use a cronjob to move the marker, and in this cronjob it needs to detect this. So javascript isn't involved!

Shape of polygon is not just a circle or square. It could be for example a country or sea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is now a function in the Google Map API that does that.

[Google Map coordinates in polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

```
containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon);    
isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should SELECT your polygons and SORT them in two different forms one by the x-axis, one by the y-axis, each time GROUPing them by the same parameter. then make sure the y coordinate of you marker point is between the y-coordinates of the polygon points of the same x. and that the marker y is between the x of the polygon points with the same y.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql spatial extensions, you can use [link text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_within) function