# Issues with Geofencing in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, polygon, geofence

I am new to flutter and truth be told i am really enjoying it. However, i have been stuck with a problem for a week now i  am trying to implement a geofencing application where my app get certain values from an sqlite database immediately the user enters a geofence site(A FARM to be precise). I am also new to the world of geofencing. i just need a lead of best ways to go about it (how to create the geofences(polygons) across the farms, format of saving the coordinate and so on) thanks in advance

Comment: this SO post you may find relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943711/google-maps-flutter-check-if-a-point-inside-a-polygon

Comment: in case if you want to draw the polygon on maps check this out : https://medium.com/@zeh.henrique92/google-maps-flutter-marker-circle-and-polygon-c71f4ea64498