# I need to check the marker is inside the polygon on map in flutter

Tags: fluttermap

I create map, where as user can draw the boundaries(polygon) of his area, and give exact geo-location by placing pin(marker). but my problem is that when i create this before it check the marker is inside the polygon or not.

[image: image description here]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here you can get the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943711/google-maps-flutter-check-if-a-point-inside-a-polygon), I tested the code and it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [point_in_polygon](https://pub.dev/packages/point_in_polygon) package and simply pass your point and point of polygon.

`Poly.isPointInPolygon(pointToCheckIfInPolygon, pointsOfPolygon)`